# using python tkinter for html file i/o

Tags: python, firefox, file-io, tkinter, xpcom

I have a web desktop app which writes and reads to local file system using XPCOM filepicker and it works flawlessly in firefox12. However later firefox versions (particularly current one v17) completely disables use of xpcom file functions.

I thought of passing file requests to python's tkinter  on a server on the local machine. I can open the tkinter filepicker in IDLE and from a .py or .cgi file, but how to get the file dialog to appear back in the calling html page of the app? I need that interactivity without leaving the app's page.   Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity and frequency of I/O, you could just post the parameters to a python CGI script and return the result in a JSON object

First, in JS:

```
function doIO (data) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyStatus == 4) {
      if (request.status == 200) { 
        alert('Success!');
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        // do something with response data
      }
      else { alert('Failure'!); }
    }
  };
  request.open("POST", python_cgi, true);
  request.send(data);
}
```

In python you would need to implement a CGI script to parse the data, figure out the requested I/O and perform it. Your python script could be something like the following:

```
import cgi, json, sys
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
command = form.getFirst('command')
if command == "filePicker":
    # run tkinter file picker
    # build json response object
elif commoand == "myIoCommand":
    # do some I/O
    # build json response object
print "Status: 200"
print "Content-Type: application/json"
json.dump(response, sys.stdout)
```

See for example [Google Maps' JSON responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) if you need some inspiration forming your json response object.

If you need more frequent/complex I/O, maybe what you would have to do is set up a Python server with mirrored state to your application via smaller, more frequent AJAX calls. You can use a framework to make a RESTful app, or you can roll your own by subclassing from [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html).